# Next number in this sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

I was trying this
3,9,18,______,648
What is the missing number?
Any hints?

I am given options as:

1. 27
2. 324
3. 54
4. 108

I thought of adding the digits and then see a pattern like except 3 all the digits of the numbers add to 9, but that is for all the numbers given in the options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Perhaps square, double, square, double:
> $3^2=9$
> $9\cdot2=18$
> $18^2=\boxed{324}$
> $324\cdot2=648$

Comment: Nice observation!!!